# How can we convince our teacher to unblock Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

We are not allowed to visit Stack Overflow at school, because our teacher thinks that this page is just junk and the code that can be found there is not good enough.

He told us that if we could tell him at least 10 things why we want to use Stack Overflow, he would unlock the page.

Can you help us please?

Comment: 1. Your teacher is clueless

Comment: I know but i am not allowed to tell him that way.
Please, dont vote me down, it's a serious question.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but 10 reasons is ridiculous. Learn to be critical about what you read. Don't copy paste but understand. Then SO is just fine.

Comment: 1. Jon Skeet. 2. Eric Lippert. etc.

Comment: Without SO, I highly doubt I would be at the same skill level as I am today. Tell your teacher he is hampering your education by denying you access.

Comment: Or write down your problems and just go on it when you get home? You never know, you may figure them out before then.

Comment: And if all else fails just use a proxy, at least you'd be using it for good, we all just used it to play monkey snowfight

Comment: If you are asking us for 10 reasons to unblock then it seems you are unsure about the benefits that SO brings yourself. You should ask yourself why you want access to SO then explain that to your teacher.

Comment: 1) Stack overflow as a community is not welcoming to blatant "do my hw for me" questions

Comment: Probably your teacher is just sick of his students cheating by posting their homework on SO.

Comment: There are many places online with junk code that your teacher hasn't blocked. There's more to SO being blocked than he's letting on - Think!

Comment: Is it being _blocked_, or just not _whitelisted_?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I'd say it's actually not that unreasonable of your teacher. *Presumably*, if your teacher is any good, he's teaching you the stuff he expects you to know and then asks you to use that knowledge at the right times. Whatever you're expected to do by your teacher, you're supposed to know because he has taught it to you before. Presumably you also have access to manuals and other reference material. Presumably your teacher is there to answer any questions you may have.

What then do you need Stack Overflow for? To post questions you should know the answer to? To avoid having to read the manual?

As a programmer you're supposed to a) use your head to work things out and b) RTFM. Supposedly you have those two things, plus a mentor at your side. Stack Overflow should be your last resort if you're on your own, the manual doesn't help and there's nobody else to bounce anything off of. If you get into the habit of SO'ing everything now, while you supposedly still have access to all the material you need (brain, TFM, teacher), you're just going to become the next generation of low-quality question posters SO doesn't need.

**Working things out on your own is probably the most important skill you can learn right now. Don't waste the opportunity.**

Comment: I mean the fact that OP tries to make us answer even non-programming related questions from their teacher (why should I use SO) tells us everything we need to know. *sigh*

Answer (score 7):

You know, something just hit me:

> Take code that you think is optimal, well-written and clear, then defend it?

Sounds a lot like something you'll need to know how to do. Just sayin'

Answer (score 2):

*Looking from teacher's perspective*, he/she is worried that you guys will simply put a search query/question and get your job done with/without proper understanding of the answer.

To be frank, at the beginning I too did the same.  As I get into deep I got to know the purpose and eventually I improved my view on using Stack Overflow.

Inorder to *convince you teacher don't try to search for 10 reason instead search for 10 great question and answers which can surprise your teacher.*  Below are few such Q & A:

1. [Why is processing a sorted array faster than an unsorted
   array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11227809/1671639)
2. [What and where are the stack and
   heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/79923/1671639)
3. [How do JavaScript closures
   work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/111102/1671639)
4. [Why is subtracting these two times (in 1927) giving a strange
   result?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6841333/1671639)
5. [How to pair socks from a pile
   efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14415881/1671639)
6. [What's the difference between a URI and a
   URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1984225/1671639)

Comment: Especially the sock-sorting one will definitely convince him.

Answer (score 2):

Students are lazy by definition. If you don't care for a class, why spend hours fretting over something you don't understand, when you could search stack overflow, mindlessly copy and paste code without reading and understanding the answer. You can then go back to your game or whatever.

Your teacher knows his class: Your question is asking for other people to think for you, so in this instance your teacher is right and you should thank him.

Comment: *Students are lazy by definition* is both inaccurate and insulting.

Answer (score -8):

1. Site of learning.
2. People on here are, generally, nice.
3. The code is junk if the **programmer** writes junk.
4. Maybe he doesn't want you to use a **big pool of resources** at the **tip of your fingertips** cause he never had it. (most likely)
5. Stack Overflow is **fluid, simple** and **easy** to **get into** and **understand**.
6. Loads of programmers on here, for like every language out there; even **Pizza** (**JVM** Based) and **Smalltalk:80** derived **Squeak**. (What `scratch` uses, I believe).
7. Has he even used the site?
8. Great community.
9. Fast answers, usually. (Depending on question asked)
10. Positive feedback from many users for being a good service.

Is that enough reasons? :)

Comment: Please, please, please don't use backticks for emphasis...

Comment: Whilst the above are generally true, are they necessarily good from the teachers perspective when assessing what is best for his/her pupils. E.g. "Fast answers" - is that necessarily good for a student?

Comment: @DanielKelley Fast Answers are good for homework ;) Ahah, aside from that, fast answers are good for anything if you think about. The faster the answer comes the quicker you can get to work on debugging or whatever you're trying to do :)

Comment: @ChrisF Is that better? :)

Comment: @BlueEyesWhiteDragon - not really. I'm not sure that the emphasis is required at all...

Comment: That depends. Figuring something out on your own with the given materials instead of getting the answer delivered on a silver plate is also a necessary skill to develop, and things you have figured out yourself are typically retained better. So, fast answers are not always good, especially when you're still in an academic setting where you explicitly have the time to discover things.

Comment: Why so many DOwnvotes?